# How to animate the width and height of a UIView in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have this subview I want to add to my main view, but make it expand from the origin. I read some of the Apple documentation but I don't understand where I am making mistake. I can animate the origin of the frame, i.e. to get it slide in from wherever, but the width/height doesn't seem to animate. Code as follows:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAddContentView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 0, 150);
[self.view addSubview:customView];

customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 310, 150);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have also tried putting only the setFrame part in the animation like this:

```
customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 0, 150);
[self.view addSubview:customView];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAddContentView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 310, 150);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But it still doesn't work!

EDIT:

As per the suggestions, I have moved it to a block based animation solution, and this is the exact code:

```
NSLog(@"yourview : %@",customView);
customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 0, 150);

NSLog(@"yourview : %@",customView);
[self.view addSubview:customView];
NSLog(@"yourview : %@",customView);

//    [customView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, customView.frame.size.width, customView.frame.size.height)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     NSLog(@"yourview : %@",customView);

                     customView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5, self.view.frame.origin.y +5, 310, 150);
                     NSLog(@"yourview : %@",customView);

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

Which still doesn't work for some reason. Possible problems I see are:

1. I am loading this customView from a `nib` that is specifically 310 by 150, perhaps that is causing a problem.
2. I am not importing the correct frameworks, but since I can animate the frame.origin parts of this view, I am not sure that is the case...I have `QuartzCore` and `Core Graphics` all imported and stuff.

At each point in the log it is giving the correct stuff: for example, before the target frame the size is 0, 150, and after I set the frame its 310, 150. But the animation doesn't work!

Comment: You cannot animate height or width of a view. You can only animate its origin. If you need to get a growing effect, scale transformation is the only way to achieve it. The tricky part of a scale transform is that it always grows from center, vertically, horizontally or both. So if you want it to kind of drop of from a given point, you will have to do some work there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To make a view "grow" into place, don't animate the frame. Animate the transform.

Load your subview from the nib. Set its transform to a scale of 0:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
```

Then add it to your superview.

Inside the animation block, set the transform to identity:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

And the view will grow to normal size. You may need to fiddle with the anchor point to make it grow from the right point.

You can also change the frame within the block, but to move a view only I prefer to change the center property, you shouldn't try to set the frame if you also have a transform.

For bonus points, you can also animate to a slightly bigger than 1.0 scale, then animate back to the identity transform in a chained animation from the completion block. This makes the view "pop" out of the screen like an alert view.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more in detail about what the difference between anchor and center? The view currently looks like it has an anchor point somewhere off to the left, so it like bounces out to the right and then back to complete the animation. Just trying to level up my animation skillz

Comment: Anchor point and center are not really related. If you're seeing bouncing, you're probably still animating the frame, and not the center. It's a complex topic for a comment, I'll try to dig up a link or two later.

Comment: You can definitely animate the frame. A possible explanation is perhaps that you haven't set the clipsToBounds to TRUE, which is why you still saw the final frame instead of the clipped frame?

Comment: @BobdeGraaf you _can_ animate the frame, but if you've got transforms in place as well, you _shouldn't_. The frame is derived from the bounds and center and is undefined if the view's transform is not the identity transform.

Comment: @jrturton That's true, but it doesn't seem like the user that posed the question does :)

Comment: For drawing left to right - imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.00001f,1); then addsubview then CGPoint originalPositionAfterScalingDown = imgView.layer.position;

and inside the animation block - imgView.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity;
imgView.layer.position = originalPositionAfterScalingDown;

Comment: Scale animation has a different visual effect than frame animation - something to consider. Sometimes it's not wanted to see the subviews scaling.

Answer (score 8):

Try using a block it will be more clear.

```
 // First create the view if you haven't already 
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)]; 
// Add it as a subview. 
[myViewController.view addSubview:myView]; 


CGRect newFrameOfMyView = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f); 
/*
 * Alternatively you could just set the width/height or whatever you'd like with this: 
 * CGRect newFrameOfMyView = myView.frame; 
 * newFrameOfMyView.size.height = 200.0f; 
 * newFrameOfMyView.size.width = 200.0f; 
 */
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
     animations:^{
      myView.frame = newFrameOfMyView; 
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
     NSLog( @"woo! Finished animating the frame of myView!" ); 
}];
```

Comment: Hey, I tried using the block way of doing it, and it still doesn't work. I am getting the view from a nib file that is a set frame, does that affect how this animation works? Or are there some frameworks that I need to import to get this to work? I have already imported quartzcore/stuff such that the animation of the origin part of the frame works...

Comment: No there is nothing else that you need to import. Without animating it, and after changing the width to something other than 0, does your view show on the screen?

Comment: If it's just clear at the moment set `customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` or something.

Comment: The view shows on screen, but the width and height do not animate :-(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
customView.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5,self.view.frame.origin.y+5,0, 150);
[self.view addSubview:customView];
CGRect frame = customView.frame;
frame.size.width = 310;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
 animations:^{
  customView.frame= frame; 
 }];
```

Or if you want to use beginAnimation method instead of block Methos , Use this :

```
UIView *customView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x +5,self.view.frame.origin.y+5,0, 150)];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
CGRect frame = customView.frame;
frame.size.width = 310;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAddContentView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
customView.frame= frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: IF you are adding view from nib than why are you doing addSubview , its already in the view and frame is also set so omit first two lines....

Comment: The customView is from a Nib file, not my view. I have to use addSubview to get it to appear on top of my original view.

Comment: Hudson : it is not advisable to make new frame inside animation block , so try not to use CGRectMake to initialize new frame instead use another CGRect object like i suggested , it should work...why dont you use the same code i have written and tell me if that works...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun way of animating your views. In my example I have a touch action that will execute the block animations and a BOOL to make sure to reset the views back to their original states.

First you put 2 UIViews on a UIViewController (you can color them different colors for contrast). Connect them to your "MainViewController.h" file you create to control the big view.
The .h file should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomView;

@end
```

and your .m file should look like this:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#define kViewAnimateWithDuration 0.35f
#define kViewDelay 0.05f

@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL setTouch;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.setTouch = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    float width_tp = self.topView.frame.size.width;
    float height_tp = self.topView.frame.size.height;

    float width_b = self.bottomView.frame.size.width;
    float height_b = self.bottomView.frame.size.height;

    if ((CGRectContainsPoint(self.bottomView.frame, touchLocation)) && !self.setTouch){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kViewAnimateWithDuration
                              delay:kViewDelay
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             //Move frame or transform view
                             [self.topView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.topView.frame.origin.x, self.topView.frame.origin.y, width_tp, height_tp + 171)];

                             [self.bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bottomView.frame.origin.x, self.bottomView.frame.origin.y +171, width_b, height_b -171)];

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.setTouch = YES;
                         }];



    }
    if ((CGRectContainsPoint(self.bottomView.frame, touchLocation)) && self.setTouch) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kViewAnimateWithDuration
                              delay:kViewDelay
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             //Move frame or transform view
                             [self.topView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.topView.frame.origin.x, self.topView.frame.origin.y, width_tp, height_tp - 171)];

                             [self.bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bottomView.frame.origin.x, self.bottomView.frame.origin.y -171, width_b, height_b +171)];

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.setTouch = NO;
                         }];
    }

}
```

So just make sure the topView has some small dimensions like x:0,y:0 width:320 height:43 and bottomView like x:0 y:40 width:320 height:528. Remember to color the backgrounds different colors. Then just run the program and you should see animations.

For me I think one of the more important lines in the code is **setFrame:** that to me enables the frame to automagically redisplays the rectangle without having to use the DrawRect method. Setting the property changes the point specified by the center property and the size in the bounds rectangle accordingly.

Of course there are other fun ways to do this but I hope this can help someone make iOS look magical like it is supposed to be! Happy journeys!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.whiteBackgroundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
        // end of animation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Important points

1) Add view to your parentView before animation, with starting frame.

2) Then just give target frame inside animation block

You no longer need this since you are adding view from nib..

```
//UIVIew yourView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:YOUR_STARTING_FRAME];
//[self.view addSubview:yourView];

.........
.........
.........
```

just give the animation code on your view.. Make sure yourView is not nil (Seems to me that is the case..)

```
NSLog(@"yourview : %@",yourView);
[UIView animateWithDuration:your_duration 
                      delay:your_starting_delay 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^ {
                     yourView.frame = YOUR_TARGET_FRAME;
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

Comment: Hey I tried this but it still doesn't work, I detailed it out on the last reply here because you guys all gave similar solutions.

Comment: the custom view itself is from a nib file, not the overall view

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"yourview : %@",yourView);` prints?

Comment: <AddNewView: 0x1a29fc80; frame = (0 128; 310 150); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1a291330>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15b5a8d0>> So this log says that the frame is already 310, 150 meaning there is nothing to animate?

Comment: You should give the target frame inside the animation block not before.. if frame before animation and target animation is same, how you can see the animation?

Comment: Also make sure you are calling the animation block from main thread

Comment: So it logs the frame as 310, 150 before the animation block. Can I set the frame.size to 0,0, and then set it to 310,150 in the animation block?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:customView];`  You dont need anymore, since you are adding views in nib.

Comment: no no no, i have a normal view, and then adding a subview, which is loaded from a nib

Answer (score 0):

If your viewcontrollers viewWillLayoutSubviews (or such) sets the "initial" frame of yourView, then that apparently gets called during the animation cycle, and would therefore reset the frame set by the animation.