# How to apply scale animation on a rectangular UIView which has been rotated?

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have to draw a rectangular shape which appears to grow.

**My Approach**

1.i made a UIView subclass,say DrwArrow and in its draw rect method i am drawing my shape I am initializing it with the height required.

1. i am now adding the DrwArrow object on my view and setting its center at the required point and then applying rotation at the required angle.

3.In order to apply scale animation i am setting its rect to  0 height and the scaling it to the required height.

**Issue**

The approach works fine when the rectangle is either vertical or horizontal but when the angle is not a multiple of 90 then it scales erroneously, I guess because the height of rect changes due to rotation applied..

I need suggestion regarding the approach i should follow.

Before downvoting please gv rsn so that i can improve.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but I've just answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852333/how-to-animate-the-width-and-height-of-a-uiview-in-xcode which should help -  animate the scale transform, not the frame size.

Comment: This way my rotation is getting  lost...

Comment: You have to apply both scale and rotation transforms - you make a transform with (e.g.) CGAffineTransformMakeScale() and you add to it by CGAffineTransformScale(), where the current transform is the first parameter.